# Openlayers - Different zoom levels with a WMS layer and only one resolution

Tags: openlayers-2, wms

I am trying to implement a homemade WMS with Openlayers. I only have one "level" of images with one resolution and I would like to add different zoom lvls with those images.

Is this possible just with Openlayers ?

Comment: where do you take wms? geoserver, mapserver or anything. pls give some detail.

Comment: I am using my own images. Actually, when the WMS request is made, I catch it with Apache and a rewrite rule, and I replace the url with the location of my map pieces. I'm just using WMS for the dynamic images downloading part.

Comment: hm, where'd you get your one 'level'? I think Aragon is heading in the right direction. In order to create different levels, you might want to look for a server-side solution. Openlayers will consume WMS, but it won't generate any more content.

Comment: couldn't you use an ImageLayer? - http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/image-layer.html

Comment: That's the point, I don't want to create new levels. In the first place, we were using "Layer.Image" with one big image built with all the little ones I needed. The zoom was a simple zoom, there was no need to have 3 different images resolution to have 3 zoom lvls. This is what I would like to reproduce, but with the layer WMS instead. My "little images" are on the server the application is deployed. I'm using Java by the way.

Comment: @iant : We want to replace this layer with the WMS one because of memory problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenLayers.Map has the "client zoom" property that can help you creating zoom leves on the client side.

See the sample: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/clientzoom.html

Comment: I think this might be just what I was looking for. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The Image layer may be what you're looking for. See http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Image-js.html.